# Is it possible to pass an OrderBy expression as an argument?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I'm building a repository framework with NHibernate.  Part of my requirements include limiting the number of results returned- or forcing paging. In order for NHibernate to successfully parse the query from the IQueryable expression, it must perform OrderBy or OrderByDescending operations before any .Skip().Take() operation.

This is how my current signature is called.

```
var actualExerciseJournals = repo.GetAll( pageIndex: pageNum++, recordsPerPage: 250, orderByFirst: exerciseJournal => exerciseJournal.JOURNALDATE, orderBySecond: exerciseJournal => exerciseJournal.MEMBERID);
```

This is the interface signature.

```
IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAll(int pageIndex, int recordsPerPage, Expression<Func<TEntity, object>> orderByFirst, Expression<Func<TEntity, object>> orderBySecond, Expression<Func<TEntity, object>> orderByThird, Expression<Func<TEntity, object>> orderByFourth, params Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>[] include);
```

(The include argument is not relevant for the question)

Is it possible to have a signature that would accept something like this as the parameter?

```
var actualExerciseJournals = repo.GetAll(pageIndex: 0, recordsPerPage: 250, collectionToOrder => collectionToOrder.OrderBy(x => x.JOURNALDATE).ThenBy(y => y.MEMBERID));
```

Then I would be able to apply this expression within my repository and I would no longer have any limits on the number of orderbys or whether it's orderbydescending or what not.

Thanks

Comment: Wait, what? Why don't you just order it afterwards?

Comment: This might be a candidate to return `IQueryable<T>` instead of `IEnumerable<T>`

Comment: I have to implement the .Skip(x).Take(y) within my repository. If the .OrderBy is added afterwards then NHibernate ignores the OrderBy when it comes to doing the paging against the database.

Comment: .OrderBy(x => x.Col1).ThenBy(x => x.Col2).Skip(250).Take(250)
---- 
translates to SQL as roughly SELECT TOP 250 * FROM (SELECT TOP 500 ROWNUM(), * FROM Table ORDER BY Col1, Col2) WHERE ROWNUM BETWEEN 250 and 500

Comment: .Skip(x).Take(y).OrderBy(x => x.Col1).ThenBy(x => x.Col2) translates to roughly -----
SELECT TOP 250 * FROM (SELECT TOP 500 ROWNUM(), * FROM Table1) WHERE ROWNUM BETWEEN 250 and 500 ORDER BY Col1, Col2

Comment: @user2141723 edit that into your question (it's easier to read that way).

Comment: The only clean way that I know to add this to a repository is to create a query extension and use reflection to build the query.

Comment: Yeah, doing an expression tree or an aspect so far have seemed the only viable prospects though I need to make the interface as simple as possible since this is a framework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The lambda expression is just a function. So you should be able to use `Func<IEnumerable<TEntity>,IEnumerable<TEntity>>`.  You are effectivly wanting to pass in a function that takes in an `IEnumerable` and give out a different `IEnumerable`.